# Converting React files to Typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am in the process of learning Typescript and am converting my React project to TS. However, I've hit a bit of a roadblock and I'm not quite sure what to do with this file:

```
import { Grid } from '@material-ui/core';
import { useParams } from 'react-router-dom';
// @ts-ignore
import ProductImage from './ProductImage.tsx';
// @ts-ignore
import ProductInfo from './ProductInfo.tsx';

type Props = {
  products: {
    id: number;
    price: number;
    description: string;
    listing_type: string;
    image: string;
  }[];
  addToCart: (e: MouseEvent) => void;
  user: {
    id: number;
    isAuth: boolean;
  };
}

const Product: React.FC<Props> = ({ products, addToCart, user }) => {
  const { productId } = useParams<{productId: string}>()

  const product = products.find(product => product.id === parseInt(productId));

  return (
    <div>
      <Grid container spacing={1} style={{ maxWidth: 1100, margin: '0 auto', marginTop: '5rem' }}>
        <Grid item sm={4}>
          <ProductImage image={product?.image} />
        </Grid>
        <Grid item sm={8}>
          <ProductInfo product={product} onClick={(e: React.MouseEvent<Element, globalThis.MouseEvent>) => addToCart(e)} user={user}/>
        </Grid>
      </Grid>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Product;
```

I added the @ts-ignore lines because of errors related to importing files ending with .tsx. However, now when I try to run npm start, I get the following error:

```
TypeError: products.find is not a function
Product
src/components/products/ProductShow.tsx:27
  24 | const Product: React.FC<Props> = ({ products, addToCart, user }) => {
  25 |   const { productId } = useParams<{productId: string}>()
  26 |   console.log(products)
> 27 |   const product = products.find(product => product.id === parseInt(productId));
  28 | 
  29 |   return (
  30 |     <div>
```

(I should note that products are passed down as an array of objects from a higher component)

At this point, I'm not sure if I'm defining my prop types incorrectly or if there is another issue with how I've set everything up. Any help with either configuring my project so that .tsx files can be imported or defining my prop types correctly would be greatly appreciated!

**Here is my tsconfig.json file**

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es2016",
    "module": "esnext",
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "removeComments": true,
    "preserveConstEnums": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "strict": true,
    "jsx": "react-jsx",
    "allowJs": true,
    "checkJs": false,
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "esnext"
    ],
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true
  },
  "include": [
    "src"
  ]
}
```

Comment: This could just be that your array of products is not defined on the initial render

Comment: What is the initial value of `products` that are passed down as props?

Comment: The array of products is in the Redux store which is what is passed to this component. Also, this is a product show page, so I'm using params to determine the id of the product to display.

Comment: Using console.log, this is the array of products before the error hits: {products: Array(20), loading: false}
loading: false
products: (20) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
[[Prototype]]: Object

Comment: Each object contains the correct info - id, price, description, etc

Comment: Could you please paste your tsconfig.json file?

Comment: @DJTaylor you console log shows the issue. `products` isn't an array of objects, it's an object itself, with a key `products`. That's your array. To demonstrate, try `products.products.find`.

Comment: Ah, good catch! Trying products.products.find throws a Typescript error now, so I still think something might be wrong in how I defined my types. Here's the error: Property 'products' does not exist on type '{ id: number; price: number; description: string; listing_type: string; image: string; }[]'. Is there a better way to set this up?

Comment: The issue is how you're passing them down from the parent. `products` should be passed from the parent as an array, rather than an object. The objects in that array should match your `products` type definition.

Comment: Thank you! I need to dig into the parent components, but matching the type definition with what is actually passed down helped solve this issue.

Comment: Any thoughts on importing .tsx files? @ts-ignore seems to work but I imagine there is a better way?

Comment: Yes, you should be able to import with no extension. It's a configuration issue outside the scope of these comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The console log shared in the comments explains this issue. `products` is logging as:

```
{products: Array(20), loading: false}
```

`.find()` exists on `Array.prototype`, but is being called on an object. The prop `products` should be passed as the array of products, rather than an object.